# How to use reverse like in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

Assume that these are records in a table:

```
id       code
--------------
1         75
2         90
3         901
4         9014
5         90145
6         80
```

What is the best query to get below result with `90145` value in where clause:

```
id       code
--------------
2         90
3         901
4         9014
5         90145
```

Comment: You get that result by looking for strings beginning with 9; I get the feeling that's not quite what you meant though..?

Comment: @Ben `90` precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it sounds like you want

```
where '90145' like code ||'%';
```

Quick demo with your values an a slightly similar extra value that is excluded:

```
with t (id, code) as (
  select 1, '75' from dual
  union all select 2, '90' from dual
  union all select 3, '901' from dual
  union all select 4, '9014' from dual
  union all select 5, '90145' from dual
  union all select 6, '80' from dual
  union all select 7, '902' from dual
)
select * from t
where '90145' like code ||'%';

        ID CODE
---------- -----
         2 90   
         3 901  
         4 9014 
         5 90145
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best query to get below result with 90145 value in where clause:

What do you mean by "Reverse like"? You could use the `%` character for pattern matching the way you want. Looking at you desired output, you need a simple pattern, i.e. code values starting with `90`.

For example,

```
select * from table_name
  where "code" like '90%';
```

See this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b70c84/2) for a working example.